# How to get mongod to load configuration from /bin/mongod.cfg by default?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb server (v4.0) installed locally but I want to change the port it's listening on. I have read the docs and have created a `mongod.cfg` file in `<install>/bin/` in ANSI format with valid YAML. The following is my config:

```
net:
  bindIp: localhost
  port: 30000
storage:
  dbPath: C:\mongodb\data\db
  journal:
    enabled: true
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: C:\mongodb\data\log\mongodb.log
  quiet: true
  logAppend: true
```

I can load that explicitly when I pass in the command `mongod --config c:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.cfg` but I want it to load *every time* I restart the service.

My issues:

1. When I run just `mongod` I get an error that it can't find the data in `c:\data\...` which is not what is set in the config. It is not loading the config from that file, how can I achieve this as default behavior (or at least change the default port in some other way)?
2. When I run `mongod --config c:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.cfg` it creates a new instance of mongodb which is listening on that port, but does *not* load my databases. In the c:\mongodb\data\db folder, I have a folder `diagnostic.data` and `journal`, as well as many `.wt` files with names like `collection-[integer]-[randomNumber].wt` and `index-[integer]-[randomNumber].wt` and `_mdb.catalog.wt` and some others (including a few WiredTiger files), so I believe this is the proper directory.

EDIT:

The results of running `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`:

```json
{
  "argv": [
    "c:\\MongoDB\\bin\\mongod.exe",
    "--config",
    "c:\\MongoDB\\bin\\mongod.cfg",
    "--service"
  ],
  "parsed": {
    "config": "c:\\MongoDB\\bin\\mongod.cfg",
    "net": {
      "bindIp": "localhost",
      "port": 30000
    },
    "processManagement": {
      "windowsService": {
        "description": "Service of MongoDB",
        "displayName": "MongoDB Service",
        "serviceName": "MongoDB"
      }
    },
    "service": true,
    "storage": {
      "dbPath": "C:\\mongodb\\data\\db",
      "journal": {
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "systemLog": {
      "destination": "file",
      "logAppend": true,
      "path": "C:\\mongodb\\data\\log\\mongodb.log",
      "quiet": true
    }
  },
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? It should load the database from `C:\mongodb\data\db` Maybe have a look at the log file.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Perhaps by accident you created another mongo service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install MongoDB as service with `mongod --config c:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.cfg --install`. Add [Windows Service Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#windows-service-options) accordingly to your mongod.cfg:

```
processManagement:
   windowsService:
      serviceName: MongoDB
      displayName: MongoDB Service
      description: Service of MongoDB
```

Then start/stop MongoDB with your [Service Manager](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/open-windows-services) or `net start MongoDB` and `net stop MongoDB` command. By default it will start with your Windows automatically.

Comment: Thank you, I've just tried this and restarted the service with `net start/stop`. For some reason, my instance is still listening on 27017 and not 30000. Peeling back the question, is there another way to just change the default port some other way? I installed MongoDB as a service when I first installed it some months ago, by the way

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had to uninstall the service with the command from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/46839299/10430070 before I could install the service again. It's now listening on port 30000 and running as a service which is exactly what I wanted. However, it still doesn't load the databases - there is nothing in the log indicating an error, and it is writing to the correct log file in the `c:\mongodb\data\db` directory

Comment: I only had one database with a half dozen collections so I just re-imported them by hand. They all imported into that `c:\mongodb\data\db` folder that I had specified in the config file, so I really have no idea why it wasn't able to see them before from the previous server. Potentially a permissions issue on the collections themselves... In any case, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Use command `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` and see what configuration is actually loaded and used.

Comment: I have just updated my question with the results. Thanks again for continuing to look.